# Many to one foreign key, return total of one when looping many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a shopping cart and a bit of a problem with storing the orders.

The logic I have is - I have 2 tables for the orders:

**Order.cs**

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public bool Shipped { get; set; } = false;

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8,2)")]
    public decimal GrandTotal { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

}
```

and **OrderDetail.cs**

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8,2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I have set up a foreign key relationship between them which works fine, and the way I get the data in the controller is:

```
List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = await _context.OrderDetails.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Where(x => x.Order.UserName == username).Include(x => x.Order).ToListAsync();
```

which also works fine, the problem is that when I loop through the list in the view, for each item in `OrderDetail` I also (of course) print out `Order`, **but** I want to print `Order` **only once**, how can I do that?

View (where I obviously loop through the whole thing and repeat Order each time, but I do not know how to not do that)

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.ProductName <br />
    @item.Quantity <br />
    @item.Price <br />
    @item.Image <br />
    // I want the code below **once**
    @item.Order.GrandTotal <br />
    @item.Order.DateTime <br />
    @item.Order.Shipped <br />
}
```

I guess I could get the order info in the controller and pass it to the view as well, but what if I have multiple orders for the same username, that is the main problem.

Comment: You could get an order with order details instead of order details with an order.

Comment: @topsail Do you mean to change just my `List<OrderDetail> orderDetails` code or the tables structure? I can have more than one row for `OrderDetail`, each linked to one and the same `Order`

Comment: This is just what I would normally do. My model (for the view) would be an Order. I would pass to my view an Order, which has its OrderDetails (because it does). Then  you can loop over each order detail item in the order's OrderDetails, pretty much what you do now.

Comment: Identifying orders by username is probably going to hurt you because ultimately a user can have more than one order.

Comment: Given your current code a bandaid would be just to not print the order information inside the loop. If you do need the order information, you can get it from the first order detail item (it will be the same for every order detail item).

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that? As I said in the Q, I could do it in the controller if there was one order only for each user, but not if there are many orders for one user.

Comment: That is all up to you. You can always send a List of Orders to your view, if you want many orders to be handled on the same page.

Comment: You may need to decide what this page is doing. I don't normally see in real life a page where all a user's order details would be listed without being somehow separable by the orders they belong to ... it's really just all up to you though. If your thought is just to list every order detail item from all orders as one big list being printed out ... then you have to decide what to do about the order information. We can't make it go away. You either print it or you don't, or you devise some kind of sectioned report or use some trick to hide repeated data ... something like that.

Comment: Yea, if I don't find a way for this I guess I will just split it into 2 separate views, which might make more sense.

Comment: As suggested in the first comment, change the view model to be List<Order> and loop through the order details of each order.  Then you have a distinct place in the code to render the order information if needed.

Comment: You need to add the `ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails` to your Order model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options: Update your Order entity to contain the list of OrderDetails:

```
public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; protected set; } = new List<OrderDetail>();
```

... and configure the relationship so Order

```
.HasMany(o => o.OrderDetails)
.WithOne(od => od.Order);
```

Then update your view's Model to use Order instead of a collection of OrderDetails. You fetch the order with it's details and provide that to the view:

```
var order = context.Orders
    .Include(o => o.OrderDetails)
    .Single(o => o.OrderId == orderId);
```

In the view you can use the order, and then iterate through its details:

```
foreach (var item in Model.OrderItems)
{
    @item.ProductName <br />
    @item.Quantity <br />
    @item.Price <br />
    @item.Image <br />
}
Model.GrandTotal <br />
Model.DateTime <br />
Model.Shipped <br />
```

Option 2 is to use projection to structure the data your view actually needs. Passing the entire Order and OrderDetails where not all columns are needed in the view. This involves creating view models:

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public decimal GrandTotal { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public bool Shipped { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderDetailViewModel> { get; set; } = new List<OrderDetailViewModel>();
}

[Serializable]
public class OrderDetailViewModel
{
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Then when reading:

```
var order = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.OrderId == orderId)
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        OrderId = o.OrderId,
        GrandTotal = o.GrandTotal,
        DateTime = o.DateTime,
        Shipped = o.Shipped,
        OrderDetails = o.OrderDetails
            .Select(od => new OrderDetailViewModel
            {
                OrderDetailId = od.OrderDetailId,
                ProductName = od.ProductName,
                Quantity = od.Quantity,
                Price = od.Price,
                Image = od.Image
            }).ToList()
    }).Single();
```

The advantage of this approach is it avoids loading more data than is necessary and makes the data "safe" to send to the view in case the view JavaScript might want to deserialize the model data. It also lets you format values, flatten data if needed, etc. to suit the view.

Comment: Would the first solution work with more than one order? I do not get a single order but a  list.

Comment: Yes, it only applies to the relationship between the order and order details where each order contains several details. You would then have a model being a List of Orders with two nested for loops, one for orders, then an inner one for details. Be careful with pulling nested entities as this can result in large query results forming a Cartesian Product via JOINs.  For reading lists of nested entities you should consider summarizing results with asynchronous calls to fetch details as needed to avoid passing/rendering potentially large results.